# Best way to assign list values to a 2D list

Tags: python, list

What is the best way to assign a list of value to a 2D list with different indices?

```
temp_list = [2, 1, 1, 5]
```

I want to iterate thru a 2D list:

```
list_to_assign =
          [[0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0],
           [2, 0, 0, 1000],
           [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

For every value of `temp_list`, I want to assign that value to the zero index of every inner list in the 2D list.

My desired result is

```
[[2, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 1000],
[5, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, try using this list comprehension below:

```
print([[x] + y[1:] for x,y in zip(temp_list,list_to_assign)])
```

Output:

```
[[2, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1000], [5, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(temp_list)):
    list_to_assign[i][0] = temp_list[i]
```

Comment: Thank you. I'd actually like to step thru my 2D list column by column. Every iteration, I get a new temp_list,  assign the temp_list to the column, and clear the temp_list.  My code is below, but it is not working. Thank you!                                                                        
                                                                                                                                   for j in range(list_to_assign.get_grid_width()):
    for i in range(len(temp_list)):
         list_to_assign[i][j] = temp_list[i]
         temp_list = []